# High order function for saga to inject an argument for saga functon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have many sagas that use a global parameter `country` and in each saga I must use reselect to take it from store.

```
const country = yield select(makeSelectCountry));
const filtersWithCountry = {
  ...filters,
  country,
};
```

And each time like this. Then I just do POST request with `filtersWithCountry`. Is there any way to make some high order function for example that while using it. it would inject `country` argument for our sagas.

Comment: Perhaps simply extract common template into an extra function, and then call it in other sagas, no?

Comment: Its rather not the way I would like to do it. I would like to make it as high order function and just by it inject it

Answer (score 1):

You just prepare it like every other higher order function:

```
const withCountry = (saga) => {
  return function*(...args) {
    const country = yield select(makeSelectCountry());
    yield saga(country, args);
  };
};
```

And now your saga should look like:

```
function* exampleSaga (country) {
  ... 
  ...
  const filtersWithCountry = {
    ...filters,
    country,
  };
  ...
  ...
};
```

And finally use it like:

```
withCountry(exampleSaga)
```